# How to prevent CCMenuItemLabel or CCMenu from changing font size on tapping?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

When I tap on CCMenuItemLabel made from CCLabelTTF, I'm getting that animation that text increases in size while it is tapped, and it all botches my interface. How do I fix that? I don't want menu to react on tapping. I have not found anything relevant in CCMenuItemLabel or in CCMenuItem or in CCMenu.

I have found this code for CCMenuItemLabel:

```
-(void) selected
{
    // subclass to change the default action
    if(_isEnabled) {
        [super selected];

        CCAction *action = [self getActionByTag:kCCZoomActionTag];
        if( action )
            [self stopAction:action];
        else
            _originalScale = self.scale;

        CCAction *zoomAction = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.1f scale:_originalScale * 1.2f];
        zoomAction.tag = kCCZoomActionTag;
        [self runAction:zoomAction];
    }
}

-(void) unselected
{
    // subclass to change the default action
    if(_isEnabled) {
        [super unselected];
        [self stopActionByTag:kCCZoomActionTag];
        CCAction *zoomAction = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.1f scale:_originalScale];
        zoomAction.tag = kCCZoomActionTag;
        [self runAction:zoomAction];
    }
}
```

As it turns out, it runs zoom action, any way to override this besides subclassing menu item?

Comment: search the menu/item code again for uses of "scale" (property or action), it's in there somewhere.

Comment: I ended up subclassing and not [super selected/unselected] so that this code would not be invoked. I did however implement in my methods whatever was in this code's super : the CCMenuItem class (trivial, look it up). Either way , subclassing like i did or straight-up modifying CCMenuItemLabel are a poor choice : both leave me with a maintainability question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I randomly came up with a dirty hack for this, someone might be interested.
In my game when I show menus, the game is paused anyway.

So I call `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];`

This slows down framerate and pauses all actions, so tapping on the menu item no longer triggers action, well it does trigger it, but it does not run, since it is paused.

Upon leaving the menu use simple `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];`

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you want to pause the director

I would look into overriding the CCMenuitemlabel

look at the following method:

```
-(void) selected

{
    // subclass to change the default action
    if(isEnabled_) {
        [super selected];

        CCAction *action = [self getActionByTag:kCCZoomActionTag];
        if( action )
            [self stopAction:action];
        else
            originalScale_ = self.scale;

        CCAction *zoomAction = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.1f scale:originalScale_ * 1.2f];
        zoomAction.tag = kCCZoomActionTag;
        [self runAction:zoomAction];
    }
}
```

i would remove the zoom action with the wierd default scaling

```
[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.1f scale:originalScale_ * 1.2f];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel very good to make a subclass and have an extra file in project just to fix this zoom issue.

You could create a CCNodeRGBA object, set contentsize same as your CCLabelTTF dimensions, paste your CCLabelTTF into CCNodeRGBA object and pass it to CCMenuItemSprite as a param.